# Communication with Serial Port - iOS Swift

Tags: java, ios, swift, sockets, socket.io

I decided to work on an open source project.
The project includes communication with serial port. And here is [link](http://www.stellarjourney.com/index.php?r=site/software_telescope) to the general command reference that it accepts over communication with serial port.
The developer of the project gave me a hint(Java code) on how it would connect, and how would I read/write data to the serial port.
Here's what he said:

A call to create the socket (typically to 192.168.0.1 and port 9999):

```
Socket s=new Socket(ip,port);
```

And a couple of objects to do the work:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

char c;
out.write(":MS#");
if (in.ready()) c=in.read();
```

The mentioned Code includes connection over Socket. How would I do the same in iOS Swift.
A few hints would be appreciated.

Comment: There are in-built socket services like [CFNetwork](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork) and the new [Network framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network) (iOS12 only - still beta) but it might be simpler to use a library like [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)

Comment: I will give it a shot. Though I can't figure how the communication is gonna work. 
Any advice would be highly appreciated :D

Comment: From a quick look it seems that the "serial port" is actually a terminal server listening on a TCP socket. You open a network connection to that socket and any data you send on the output stream gets sent out of the serial port and any data sent to the serial port gets delivered over the input stream associated with the connection

Comment: Awesome! I'm gonna give it a shot. Thank you.

Comment: You will need to be comfortable with handling asynchronous events as polling the serial port for data or blocking wating for input isn't a good idea

Comment: Doesn't sound very rough. Thanks for kind advice ;)

Comment: @Paulw11 I managed to make a communication with the TCP socket. And it does reply upon a request. 
Though it terminates the connection within a second, I'm still figuring out that.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a range of options from IOKit, POSIX, Darwin/MachKernel.  In short, surprisingly complex for a simple thing! It is so because of serial port's legacy.

The popular framework to insulate you from this in Swift is ORSSerialPort. Good docs for this open source project too. There is also https://github.com/kpishere/POSIXSerialPort. Patterned in same way but much simpler and with no dependancy to IOKit.  It uses POSIX api in Macos and also some Mach kernel specific apis for threading and signaling abstractions.

Comment: Yes! This might help future viewers.
Back then I achieved what i was after.
Here's what i built: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/gotomote/id1445152416